# How to clean up /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages under Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, macos, pip

So I was messing around following all kinds of tutorials telling me to sudo pip install instead of doing it right by using a virtualenv for properly handling what my individual web apps need. The result is a bunch of stuff in my site-packages and I was wondering what the actual default would be so I can pip uninstall (or can I just delete the folders?) to set this back to Mac OS X default and then do it nicely in my virtualenv.

I could not find an answer how to "reset your site-packages" or what is installed by default.

I currently have:

```
GitPython-0.3.2.RC1.dist-info
Jinja2-2.8.dist-info
MarkupSafe-0.23.dist-info
README
Twisted-15.4.0-py2.7.egg-info
autocomplete_light
bench.egg-link
bootstrap3
bootstrap3_datetime
characteristic-14.3.0.dist-info
characteristic.py
characteristic.pyc
click
click-4.1.dist-info
crispy_forms
cssselect
cssselect-0.9.1.dist-info
django_autocomplete_light-2.2.10-py2.7.egg-info
django_bootstrap3-6.2.2.dist-info
django_bootstrap3_datetimepicker-2.2.3-py2.7.egg-info
django_crispy_forms-1.5.2-py2.7.egg-info
django_epic-0.2.7-py2.7.egg-info
easy-install.pth
epic
et_xmlfile
et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py2.7.egg-info
git
gitdb
gitdb-0.6.4.dist-info
honcho
honcho-0.6.6.dist-info
jdcal-1.2-py2.7.egg-info
jdcal.py
jdcal.pyc
jinja2
lxml
lxml-3.5.0.dist-info
markupsafe
openpyxl
openpyxl-2.3.1-py2.7.egg-info
pip
pip-7.1.2.dist-info
pyasn1
pyasn1-0.1.9.dist-info
pyasn1_modules
pyasn1_modules-0.0.8.dist-info
queuelib
queuelib-1.2.2.dist-info
requests
requests-2.7.0.dist-info
semantic_version
semantic_version-2.4.2.dist-info
service_identity
service_identity-14.0.0.dist-info
smmap
smmap-0.9.0.dist-info
test_characteristic.py
test_characteristic.pyc
twisted
vboxapi
vboxapi-1.0-py2.7.egg-info
virtualenv-13.1.0.dist-info
virtualenv.py
virtualenv.pyc
virtualenv_support
w3lib
w3lib-1.13.0.dist-info
wheel
wheel-0.24.0.dist-info
```

Comment: Given that your virtualenvs shouldn't have access to the global packages, why not just ignore the `site-packages`?

Comment: I know I could just ignore it but I feel like I have created a mess I would like to clean up

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to clear *everything* installed by `pip` is as follows:

1. Create a list of installed packages `pip freeze > all.txt`; and
2. Uninstall everything on it `pip uninstall -r all.txt`.

You'll probably have to hit `y` a few times, but otherwise everything should be fine, and it'll leave you with a list of the packages you had in case you forget.

Comment: OK but that would potentially mess with things that were shipped with Mac OS X so deleting everything could backfire.

Comment: @JackMurphy you can edit the file between steps 1 and 2 if necessary, or reinstall packages if you break something.